# How to check the functions queue for async execution?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

I don't know if I have described clearly enough of this title. I'd better to show you the code:

There's 4 functions here, and I want to create a async execution with some of them:

```
function a(){
    console.log('a');
}
function b(){
    console.log('b');
}
function c(){
    console.log('c');
}
function d(){
    console.log('d');
}

a();
setTimeout(b, 1);
setTimeout(c, 0);
d();
```

This logs:

> 'a'
>   'd'
>   'b'
>   'c'

And it return a different result to change my code into this:

```
function a(){
    console.log('a');
}
function b(){
    console.log('b');
}
function c(){
    console.log('c');
}
function d(){
    console.log('d');
}

a();
setTimeout(b, 2); // delay seconds for b have been changed here
setTimeout(c, 0);
d();
```

This logs:

> 'a'
>   'd'
>   'c'
>   'b'

My execution environment is in Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 MacOSX.

My question is:

When I set the delay second for b to 2, it have a totally different execution result. What is the differences between setTimeout(b, 1) and setTimeout(b, 2) ?

Could anybody give me a hand? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you look this up? If so, what did you find? Also, it would probably be good to show how the results are different.

Comment: Well, my point is: I don't know why this comes from a different result. Am I make something mistake?@Anonymous

Comment: Besides that, I already show you the result with a statement comment.

Comment: I know what setTimeout does. What I want to ask is: what is the different between the delay 1 millisecond and delay 2 millisecond~?@Anonymous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(b, 2);
```

The above code does not delay 2 seconds, it is 2 milliseconds.
I am not sure ,maybe this is the reason, because javascript executes codes line by line. So when you use

```
setTimeout(b, 1);
setTimeout(c, 0);
```

It has already passed 1 millisecond ,so it will execute function b directly because parsing next line of code costs time.

I have done a test to prove it.

```
a();
t1 = setTimeout(b, 2); 

//javascript will parse and execute the following code ,and this costs some milliseconds.
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
   console.log('no.'+i);
}

t2 = setTimeout(c, 0);
d();
```

The result is:

```
d
b  
c
```

Comment: If the reason is javascript executes code line by line, why the result delay for 1 or 2 second is different? I cannot understand this.

Comment: It is milliseconds!  You computer needs this time to parse and execute js code.

Comment: Sorry, I know it millisecondes. I am not very good in English. : (   Besides this, if the computer need this time to execute js code. Then if I set the delay ms for b is 12 and delay ms for c is 11. The return a different result with demo1. Why~?

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers have a minimum temporal resolution for scheduling. HTML5 sets the minimum at 4ms. If you request anything under 4ms, it will execute some time after 4ms. I am reasonably-but-not-100%-certain that you are seeing unpredictable behaviour - i.e. both of your examples should come out as `adcb` some time, and `adbc` at other times.

[HTML5 Spec, Timers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#timers):

> 1. If nesting level is greater than 5, and timeout is less than 4, then increase timeout to 4.

Comment: It didn't make sense. If the reason is HTML5 minimum delay/interval seconds. Then why the result delay for 1 or 2 second is different?

Comment: Could be the browser's internal implementation detail. The point is, you cannot be sure when things are going to be scheduled. If you need things to happen in certain order while being asynchronous, you should use promises.